# JavaScript — Split an array like a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to split an array into smaller arrays each time a specific value is found? In this case, every time `type` equals `"divider"`.

Input:

```
[
    {
        "type": "type-a",
        "name": "Foo"
    },
    {
        "type": "type-b",
        "name": "Foo"
    },
    {
        "type": "type-c",
        "name": "Foo"
    },
    {
        "type": "divider",
        "name": "Foo"
    },
    {
        "type": "type-b",
        "name": "Foo"
    },
    {
        "type": "type-b",
        "name": "Foo"
    },
    {
        "type": "divider",
        "name": "Foo"
    },
    {
        "type": "type-c",
        "name": "Foo"
    }
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
    [
        {
            "type": "type-a",
            "name": "Foo"
        },
        {
            "type": "type-b",
            "name": "Foo"
        },
        {
            "type": "type-c",
            "name": "Foo"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "type": "type-b",
            "name": "Foo"
        },
        {
            "type": "type-b",
            "name": "Foo"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "type": "type-c",
            "name": "Foo"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: what did you try till now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [break array of objects into separate arrays based on a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696326/break-array-of-objects-into-separate-arrays-based-on-a-property)

Comment: @pilchard I'm not sure that's exactly the same question. The other question is a classic "group by", here's it's a little bit different but I am sure it's been asked before.

Comment: This is probably closer to what OP wants — https://stackoverflow.com/q/34513679/1244884

Comment: @customcommander too true, I didn't look at the dupe closely enough. perhaps: [Split an array of objects in to two, based on a value within the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945891/split-an-array-of-objects-in-to-two-based-on-a-value-within-the-object) but adapted for multiple divisions, or yours which just needs adapting to objects (a shame `findIndex` doesn't have a `fromIndex` param as `indexOf` does)

Comment: Ahmed - I tried reducing and pushing to a new array, but I only managed to group them by types (similar to the link pilchard posted and other related questions). 

I couldn't find any similar threads with this exact need in here, so I'm not sure why it gets downvoted.

However, all 3 provided answers gives the desired response, so that's pretty awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` here as:

```js
const arr = [{ "type": "type-a", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "type-b", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "type-c", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "divider", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "type-b", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "type-b", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "divider", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "type-c", "name": "Foo" }];

const temp = [];
const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.type === 'divider') {
    acc.push([...temp]);
    temp.length = 0;
  } else {
    temp.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
if (temp.length) result.push([...temp]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```js
const arr = [{ "type": "type-a", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "type-b", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "type-c", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "divider", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "type-b", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "type-b", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "divider", "name": "Foo" }, { "type": "type-c", "name": "Foo" }];

function divide(container, divider) {
  const final = [];
  let tmp = new Array();
  for (let item of container) {
    if (item.type === divider) {
      final.push(tmp);
      tmp = new Array();
    }
    item.type !== divider && tmp.push(item)
  }

  tmp.length > 0 && final.push(tmp)
  return final;
}

const res = divide(arr, 'divider');

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Search each object of the array and till you find the `divider` one, push all the objects into another array.

If `divider` is found, then increment the index, ignore this object and continue.

```js
let arr=[{"type":"type-a","name":"Foo"},{"type":"type-b","name":"Foo"},{"type":"type-c","name":"Foo"},{"type":"divider","name":"Foo"},{"type":"type-b","name":"Foo"},{"type":"type-b","name":"Foo"},{"type":"divider","name":"Foo"},{"type":"type-c","name":"Foo"}]

let finalArr = []
let currentIndex = 0;

for (let obj of arr) {
  if (obj.type === 'divider') {
    currentIndex++;
  } else {
    (finalArr[currentIndex] = finalArr[currentIndex] || []).push(obj);
  }
}

console.log(finalArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a curried recursive function:

The first parameter is a predicate function that takes an element and decides whether that element is a delimiter. Then it takes an array and splits it into chunks. Each chunk contains the elements in between (but excluding) a delimiter element.

```js
const splitBy = pred => function loop([x, ...xs], ret = [[]]) {
  if (x == null) return ret;
  if (pred(x)) ret.push([]);
  else ret[ret.length-1].push(x);
  return loop(xs, ret);
}

const isDivider = x => x.type == 'divider';
const splitByDivider = splitBy(isDivider);

splitByDivider([ { "type": "type-a" , "name": "Foo" }
               , { "type": "type-b" , "name": "Foo" }
               , { "type": "type-c" , "name": "Foo" }
               , { "type": "divider", "name": "Foo" }
               , { "type": "type-b" , "name": "Foo" }
               , { "type": "type-b" , "name": "Foo" }
               , { "type": "divider", "name": "Foo" }
               , { "type": "type-c" , "name": "Foo" }]);

//=> [ [ { "type": "type-a", "name": "Foo" }
//=>   , { "type": "type-b", "name": "Foo" }
//=>   , { "type": "type-c", "name": "Foo" } ]
//=> , [ { "type": "type-b", "name": "Foo" }
//=>   , { "type": "type-b", "name": "Foo" } ]
//=> , [ { "type": "type-c", "name": "Foo" } ]]
```